# Auto Timezone doesn't update

Tags: time, ubuntu-gnome, timezone

[Running Ubuntu Gnome 15.10]

I recently brought my computer from PST to EST in North America.  Once in EST my laptop did not update the timezone.  I tried toggling the "Auto Time Zone" switch which had no effect.  Finally, I rebooted the machine which also didn't have an effect.

Running `/usr/lib/geoclue-2.0/demos/where-am-i` doesn't return any result.

Comment: Try [this](http://www.watchingthenet.com/enable-auto-time-synchronization-in-ubuntu-and-kubuntu.html) tutorial. I think this is just what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Alex, that tutorial is 8 years old at this point, and dates back to when Ubuntu was still using Gnome 2.x.  The issue I'm having isn't with ntp which is installed and functioning.  It's that my computer cannot figure out where it is, via the geoclue system.  That's what changes the timezone.  The "time" is accurate, but just the wrong timezone.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

For Ubuntu 18.04+ make sure Settings -> Privacy -> Location Services is set to "On."

Comment: This is actually the key to solving the issue.

Comment: Does it default to "off" or did I manually change that? It's weird that the "Automatic Time Zone" feature just silently fails without warning or explanation.

Comment: @MichaelMartin-Smucker yeah... they really should warn, or prompt you to enable/re-enable Location Services

Comment: need Settings>Date&Time> Automatically Date & Time and Timezone on. As well as privacy location settings on.

Comment: So the bug, it seems, is with the Date and Time interface. A user shouldn't be able switch a dependant (child) feature "on" that cannot function without Location Services: in my opinion, switching Automatic Timezone to on should first check if Location Services are on and then redirect the user accordingly.

Comment: @GrayedFox: agree. Have you filed a bug?

Comment: I think [this](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/issues/67) is the most relevant open bug

Answer (score 8):

I seem to have fixed this issue by installing `gnome-clocks` which might serve as the hook gnome-shell uses to get the location data for the time-zone.

Comment: Still works with Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: Sloved this issue for me on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Also works on Mint 18 Sarah. Thx.