# How can I make Ubuntu automatically detect the correct timezone based on my internet connection?

Tags: networking, internet, time, timezone

My default location is GMT+1. I would like Ubuntu to automatically change my default timezone based on the timezone of my connected internet connection.

**Example:**

When I am in Portugal, and connected to an internet connection, I want Ubuntu to change my timezone setting from GMT+1 to GMT+0.

Moreover, I ensured that the following settings are set but they do not make my timezone change:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related question on Unix SE https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/90325/49853

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a script in GitHub to detect and update the current time zone, using geolocation from your IP address: https://github.com/cdown/tzupdate

Once python and python-pip are installed, the script can be installed as:

```
pip install -U tzupdate
```

And run as

```
sudo ~/.local/bin/tzupdate
```

This command could be somehow automatically run on startup.

Comment: Note that /etc/rc.local won't work for running the script automatically, since at that stage the newtork may not yet be available.

Answer (score 4):

For Ubuntu 18.04 make sure Settings -> Privacy -> Location Services is set to "On."

Solution provide by glortho
[Auto Timezone doesn't update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726399/auto-timezone-doesnt-update)

It automatically works right away.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 20.04 you can run the command as current logged-in user ( running as root doesn't change your current user timezone setting )

```
gsettings set org.gnome.system.location enabled true
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.datetime automatic-timezone true
```