# Kubuntu 22.10 automatically adjust timezone without user interraction

Tags: kubuntu

I traveled to San Diego and noticed my time zone was still in Phoenix, Arizona. I had to manually go into `System Settings > Date & Time > Time Zone` and change it to Los Angeles (Pacific) to get the corrected time on my laptop.

I researched this issue and found two articles, but they were not associated with Kubuntu 22.10. It was for Ubuntu 20.04 (I know they are both Ubuntu flavor distributions):

1. [Ubuntu 20.04 Location Services setting is grayed out in
   settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1271321/ubuntu-20-04-location-services-setting-is-grayed-out-in-settings)
2. [How can I make Ubuntu automatically detect the correct timezone
   based on my internet connection?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/738513/how-can-i-make-ubuntu-automatically-detect-the-correct-timezone-based-on-my-inte)

According to the first article, there is a Github script that can update timezones based on IP address geolocation.

Is there a permanent fix for this issue besides running a script?

Comment: I'd wait for someone else to comment, but I set my system to manually changes, as I have a *dynamic* IP address at home, and my ISP (*internet service provider*) can allocate me IP addresses that have my location on the other side of the country (*where their head office is actually*) which is 3 hours behind my local time..   To avoid my time being something I need to check (ie. *automatic*) I have opted to have it manually; as at least I'm aware when I'm away from home.  Could you have changed your default to *static* for to avoid surprises due to *dynamic* IP & auto-location?

Comment: @guiverc not I have not. I just reinstall kubuntu 22.10 on my laptop yesterday (No Dual) and I am having this issue.

Comment: The re-install doesn't tell me much, as if you used a non-destructive re-install, any [user] settings you had on the prior install survive the re-install process.  I don't install Kubuntu often, so I'm not the person to advice on what Kubuntu's defaults are sorry (*and don't have time currently to look up; I'd suggest waiting for others to comment/answer*)

Comment: When I travel, I want the laptop to keep the original time zone. Changing time zones without warning mucks with calendar appointments, and it's best if everybody shows up at the correct time.